# vite:vue Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vite

hoy me desperte con este error que la verdad no hay mucho en la web que pueda resolver, el problema es con vue y Vite, antes de un o dos updates me funcionaba pero ahora me arroja este error, alguien tiene conocimiento de que pueda ser?

```
[plugin:vite:vue] Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'.
D:/laragon/www/webookyou/vue/src/views/partials/SearchForm.vue:264:30
262|      },
263|      disabledDate(time) {
264|        return time.getTime() < moment().hour(-1);
   |                               ^
265|      },
```

es al momento de hacer la condicion del "<"

Comment: No tengo idea de vue pero... algo de esto te sirve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077970/illegal-tag-name-use-lt-to-print-on-nuxt-project

Comment: Ese seria con nuxtjs pero aun asi no es lo correcto, gracias de todos modos